# Angular *ngIf displays a div without content

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, angular-ng-if

I have an array with objects, each having a type.
I want to display only the objects with a specific type that i change by pressing some buttons.
For some reasons, for the "Food" type, it also renders the other two objects but without any content.

Here's the array and type

```
  objects = [
    {
      title: 'Spartan Sandwich',
      price: 4,
      type: 'Food',
    },
    {
      title: 'Math Lessons',
      price: 10,
      type: 'Necesities',
    },
    {
      title: 'Ice Skating',
      price: 10,
      type: 'Misc',
    },
  ];
  type: string = 'Food';
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="objects">
  <div class="object-container" *ngFor="let object of objects">
    <app-object [object]="object" *ngIf="object.type === type"></app-object>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know that it's normal for it to always render all the object-container divs, but how can i fix it so that they do not appear?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the `ngFor` loop in `ng-content` and check the `object.type` in `object-container` div:

```
<div class="objects">
  <ng-content *ngFor="let object of objects">
    <div class="object-container" *ngIf="object.type === type">
      <app-object [object]="object"></app-object>
    </div>
  </ng-content>
</div>
```

**Note:** `ng-content` doesn't render any `HTML` element.

Answer (score 1):

Either you go with the code suggested by Shuvo or you manipulate the "objects" array using filter.

```
viewData = this.objects.filter(({ type }) => type === this.type);
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by putting the `app-object` component inside a virtual container like `ng-container` that way there will not be any need to use an extra div.

The code will look like this:
`

```
<div class="objects">
  <div class="object-container" *ngFor="let object of objects">
    <ng-container *ngIf="object.type === type">
       <app-object [object]="object"></app-object>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

`